qt6-make make: *** No rule to make target 'mainwindow.ui', needed by 'ui_mainwindow.h'
I made a simple QT gui application through QTCreator. It is running well on my Linux 20.04
Now, I want to build this application in yocto to make it run on imx8mp board.
I have created a hello-gui_1.0.0.bb file
SUMMARY = "QT Demo GUI Application"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "file://HelloGUI.pro \
           file://main.cpp \
           file://mainwindow.cpp"

DEPENDS += " \
        qtbase \
        qtdeclarative \  
        packagegroup-qt6-modules \
        wayland \
"

RDEPENDS_${PN} += "qtwayland"

S = "${WORKDIR}"
    
inherit qt6-qmake

I created directory and file structure as below
hello-gui
|--hello-gui_1.0.0.bb
|--files
   |--HelloGUI.pro
   |--main.cpp
   |--mainwindow.cpp
   |--mainwindow.h
   |--HelloGUI.pro.user
   |--mainwindow.ui

I am continuously getting below an error shown below
| make: *** No rule to make target 'mainwindow.ui', needed by 'ui_mainwindow.h'.  Stop.
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.

Is there any dependency that I missed?
I have created this application on QT5 and yocto has QT6. Is that fine?
